# tested preg_replace not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following

```
$string = 'Trials <- load.dataset("Foo, Bar")';  
$pattern[0] = "/(?:load.dataset|\"Foo, Bar?)\"/";

$replacement[0] = '"/my/path/JohnDoe.csv"';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

echo $pattern[0]; // /(?:load.dataset|"Foo, Bar?)"/
echo $replacement[0]; // "/my/path/JohnDoe.csv"
```

However, the replacement do not look like it's working;

```
echo $string; // Trials <- load.dataset("Foo, Bar")
```

I have tested my Regex with [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) and it works fine there so I am not sure where I have made a mistake.

Why the replacement does not happen?

Comment: @chris85 typo from the question. Updated it

Comment: @chris85. Yes. That wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preg_replace` needs to be assigned to your variable.

As is this:

```
$string = 'Trials <- load.dataset("Foo, Bar")';  
$pattern[0] = "/(?:load.dataset|\"Foo, Bar?)\"/";
$replacement[0] = '"/my/path/JohnDoe.csv"';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Replaces on the fly, try updating to:

```
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

From the manual:

> If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged or NULL if an error occurred.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I will accept in 3 minutes. Thank you